Dynamic routes based on ID with multiple optional sub sections
I am implementing dynamic routing in Astro SSR mode, based on the id.
I can have different routes, with the id on various place like:
foo/bar/12345/my-path
foo/bar/section/12345/my-path
bar/foo/section/another-section/12345/my-path
etc...

How do I greb the id from the route in my Astro page something like:
pages/[section]/[subsection]/[id].astro
How do I greb the const { id } = Astro.params; when my route has different structures?

You're looking for [...id].astro it's all in the docs, they're really great.

@mb21 that's not working because of the structure of the routes, see my question? Or do I miss something?

Not sure exactly what you're asking. But see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/routing/#rest-parameters

from this route /foo/bar/12345/title in need the id part (12345) for my GraphQL query variable. But the route could also be /sub/sub2/section/12345/title (so another section). And then use that id variable like const { id } = Astro.params;. How do I fix that?

@mb21 is there a solution for this? Thanks
